# C-API: PySys_SetObject Reference Count

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-c-api

Does [PySys_SetObject](https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/sys.html#c.PySys_SetObject) steal the reference to the object `v` or should I decrement its reference counter?

```
PyObject *my_obj = PyUnicode_FromString("my_string_path");
int ret = PySys_SetObject("path", my_obj);
Py_XDECREF(my_obj);  // Should I decref it?
```

Should I just assume that whenever the docs don't specify that the function steals the reference I should always decrement its reference counter?

The same question for [PyList_Append](https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/list.html#c.PyList_Append) ([PyList_SetItem](https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/list.html#c.PyList_SetItem) specifies the stealing behavior).

Answer (score 1):

> Should I just assume that whenever the docs don't specify that the function steals the reference I should always decrement its reference counter?

Apparently yes. When calling `PySys_SetObject("name", v)` it does increment `v` reference counter. It also decrements the reference counter of whichever object there is in the sys module named `"name"`, if it exists.